Would applying for STEM-OPT extension after getting H1B Approved but not Activated affect H1B
I am currently on my OPT and my EAD expires on 16th Aug. I am eligible for the STEM-OPT extension. My H1B has been approved and I have received a physical copy of Form I-797A from USCIS. I am on H1B CapGap until 1st Oct at present.
I have two questions:

If I get laid off and my employer retracts the H1-B petition, would mine being selected for the H1B lottery go waste? Further, if I am able to find another employer who'd agree to H1B transfer within 60 days of losing my job, can I continue to work as a H1B visa holder without going through the lottery process again?

If I apply for the STEM-OPT extension before 16th Aug and I do not lose my job, will it affect mine moving on H1B on 1st Oct? In other words, will applying for the STEM-OPT extension jeopardise my H1B?


I am extremely anxious about whether I should apply for the STEM-OPT extension as a backup, without jeopardising my H1B.

Hey I’m in a similar situation. Did you find any solution. ??

just answered my question

I'm in a similar situation and wondering what I should do. You said that "STEM-OPT ext will not affect H1B, as long as I withdraw my STEM-OPT before 1st Oct." Why does this matter whether or not you withdraw your application? Because STEM-OPT application is not a COS application and it is an application for EAD only. After Oct 1st, this application will just be moot right?

My attorney thinks I should withdraw. No body has given me a clear answer.

After numerous efforts, this is what I know so far:

If I get fired before 1st Oct and the employer retracts H1B application, I lose the lottery.

STEM-OPT ext will not affect H1B, as long as I withdraw my STEM-OPT before 1st Oct.


Hence, Ihave applied for my STEM-OPT ext.
